# Append value to a Jtoken

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Given the following JSON

```
{
    "Cars" [
        {
            "Mercedes-Benzz": {
                "A-class": "A160,A180"
                 "B-class": "B200"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to append a value and my JSON to be like :

```
{
    "Cars" [
        {
            "Mercedes-Benz": {
                "A-class": "A160,A180,A200"
                 "B-class": "B200"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

```
var myjson= File.ReadAllText(filepath);
JObject myDocument = JObject.Parse(myjson);

var property = myDocument ["Cars"][0]["Mercedes-Benz"]["A-class"];
property.append("A200"); //<- This DO NOT WORK

File.WriteAllText(filepath,myDocument.ToString());
```

It will also be optimal, if there was a way to check if the value that I want to append already exists.

Comment: you are not actually appending to the value, you are replacing it with a new value. So grab the current value, append the extra data to the value and assign the new value back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use

```
property.append()
```

use something like

```
var myvalue = propery.ToString();
//code to edit this as you like
property = myvalue;
```